# using and(&&) operator in for loop in linux

Tags: linux, for-loop, and-operator

01) I am trying to use the && operator in a for loop as shown below in the script. However this does not seem to work. I was not able to see the error generated in the terminal window, since it closes as soon as it runs in to an error. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Documents/DTI/

#subj and subj1 contain folders which are located in the DTI directory
subj="ARN MT"
subj1="ARNpre1 ARNpre2"

for [[s in $subj] && [s1 in $subj1]]
```

02) And as you can see in my "subj1", the first two entries start with the letters ARN which means that they are sub directories of ARN(located in a different place.Not in ARN main directory). So I also want to run a command in which, if subj1 contains subj then it must perform a certain command.For this purpose I wrote the following,

```
if [[ ${s1} == *"${s}"* ]];then
```

would this be the right way to do such operation?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the actual directory structure, and how you'd expect that to match in your script?

Comment: yes. My ARN main directory contains BOLD activation masks created using MRI data and my ARNpre folder contains DTI data for ARN. But my DTI data is in a separate folder that has "subject data" and my masks are in a separate "masks" folder. the same mask(in ARN) is used for both data folders(ARNpre1 and ARNpre2).I hope that explanation is clear

Comment: No, that didn't really help. I'm not familiar with the tools  you're using. I meant you should give a simple directory structure (like the output from `ls`, but with just a few files for an example. Then give an example of which pairs of entries you would expect to match. However, you really had 2 questions here, not 1. You could just delete the second half of this question and re-post it (with the example) as a new question. That would probably help it get more attention.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I was able to get the code to work!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you figured it out. If my answer was helpful you can click the green checkmark by it to "accept" it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by `for [[s in $subj] && [s1 in $subj1]]` you mean this:

```
for s in $subj; do
  for s1 in $subj1; do
    # do something
  done
done
```

By nesting the `for` loops you'll loop through every possible combination of `s` and `s1`, which sounds like what you're trying to do in part 1 of your question.

However, I can't make sense of what you're talking about in part 2, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt reply.I tried using, for [[s in $subj] -a [s1 in $subj1]] and, for [s in $subj] -a [s1 in $subj1 but no luck. Any ideas why??

Comment: @manuweth - `-a` works in conditions, but you can't use a test like that in a for loop. Re-read my answer. After I realized you were using a `for` not an `if` I deleted the one suggesting to use `-a` and suggested this instead.